# Hide element after sweetAlert Ajax delete request

Tags: jquery, ajax, sweetalert

I want to make a ajax request to delete an image. After user confirm to the alert I want to hide the image, I don't want to reload whole page because It will make another call to db and It will take time to load whole page. 
I am trying to the same but It's not working neither does it show any error.
But When I reload the page then the image is gone, because all the content is fetched again.
*So, I want to hide the image when user confirms and make the request in background.*

**Jquery**

```
//delete uploaded image
            $(document).on("click", ".delete-image", function(e) {

                var type = $(this).data('type');
                var aurl = $(this).data('url');

                swal({
                        title: "Are you sure?",
                        text: "Do you want to delete the image?",
                        type: "warning",
                        showCancelButton: true,
                        confirmButtonColor: '#dd4b39',
                        confirmButtonText: "Yes",
                        closeOnConfirm: false,
                        showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
                    },
                    function() {

                        if (aurl) {
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "GET",
                                url: aurl,
                                success: function(response) {
                                    swal("Deleted", response.message, "success");
                                    $(this).parent().parent().hide();
                                    swal.close();
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    }
                );



            });
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
                            @forelse($images as $image)
                            <div class="col-md-4"><img src="{{$image->image_url}}" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail"> 
                            <div class="text-center">
                            <!-- Initialize ClipboardJS -->
                            <script>
                            new ClipboardJS('.clipboard');
                            </script>
                            <a data-url="upload_images/{{$image->id}}"  class="delete-image waves-effect btn btn-danger" role="button" data-type="delete"  >Delete</a>';
                            <a class="btn btn-primary waves-effect clipboard"  data-clipboard-text="{{$image->image_url}}" >Copy URL</a>
                            </div>
                            </div>                         
                            @empty
                            <p class="text-center">No image found...</p>
                            @endforelse
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ajax, delete-image will not accessible by $(this).
You need to put and kept in a variable.

```
$(document).on("click", ".delete-image", function(e) {
    var elm = $(this);

    if (aurl) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: aurl,
            success: function(response) {
                swal("Deleted", response.message, "success");
                $(elm).parent().parent().hide();
                swal.close();
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the element you want to hide, so before you make ajax call, add

```
var DivToHide = $(this);
```

then once the sweetalert has been triggered, use DivToHide variable to hide the element

```
$(DivToHide).parent().parent().fadeOut();
```